# Issue after disabling auto layout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, storyboard

My app was working good till I play with the auto layout option in storyboard. I disable the auto layout and found all views changed their alignment. Then I enable it but my views are not coming back to its original alignment, i don't understand what am I doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Can you revert back to a version of the app that does work? You are using version control, right?

Comment: Yes I do, but unfortunately I haven't updated it recently. Don't we have any other option than reverting?

Comment: @OSD if you neither use version control nor snapshotting, it can be big loss.

Comment: But why is it so? I just clicked on the auto layout option and enabled it within seconds. What is the technical reason behind it?

Comment: @OSD The technical reason is the same as the technical reason why if you burn a $100 bill you cannot make it come back by pouring water on the ashes. Destruction goes only in one direction. :) It doesn't matter how many "seconds" pass in the meantime. See my answer below.

Comment: If you didn't close the file since the change, you may be able to undo it (Edit > Undo).

Answer (score 3):

> I disable the auto layout and found all views changed their alignment. Then I enable it but my views are not coming back to its original alignment, i don't understand what am I doing wrong

You are not doing anything wrong.

The constraints that you had in auto layout were objects in the nib. When you disabled auto layout in the nib, those constraints became meaningless, so they were deleted.

Now you are turning auto layout on again. But is not going to bring the constraints back again by magic. You deleted them. They are gone. So naturally your "views are not coming back to its original alignment". How can they? There is nothing there to tell them what that "alignment" should be.

Comment: But its a tableview and i dint have any constraints on them.

Comment: I cannot see your app project and you have not described it. I am describing to you why "alignment" settings would go away and not return when you turn auto layout off and back on again. That, it seems to me, answers your question. If you have a different question, ask a different question. I answered the question you _actually asked_, based on the information you actually provided.